# Shipping cost based on the distance between seller and customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, google-api

So I was trying to find a solution of charging my customers by the distance between their locations and sellers’ locations, but couldn’t find anything suitable. I have found few plugins who does similar job like different shipping charge between warehouse and shipping location using Google API, but they deal with only one specific location as warehouse. I actually have several vendors who have warehouses in different locations.

I am using woocommerce and wc vendor plugin.

FYI..., I have set a meta field that collects vendor’s latitude and longitude using Google Api.

//An example://

> Vendor 1 – Location 1 Vendor 2 – Location 2
>
> A customer places order from vendor 1. Customer’s location is in
>   Location A. API will calculate the distance between the cart item’s
>   vendor’s location, which is Location 1, and customer’s location, which
>   is Location A.
>
> ```
> Check the cart item's Vendor
> Get the location of Vendor
>
>   If Location 1 to Location A = 3KM,
>     Shipping Charge is 50;
>   If Location 1 to Location A <= 5 KM,
>     Shipping Charge is 100;
>   Else
>     Shipping Charge is 150;
> ```

//Example Ended//

N.B. I just don’t find any plugin for distance shipping charge that works well with WC Vendor plugin. Even if you manage to give me any link of any plugin that does this job, that would be appreciated too.

---

So, @loictheaztec has provided a solution below. I have written a piece of code based on his codes. Unfortunately, it's not working for me.

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'distance_shipping_calculated_surcharge', 100, 2 );
   function distance_shipping_calculated_surcharge( $rates, $package ) {


    $shippingurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=VENDOR_LOCATION&destinations=CUSTOMER_LOCATION&key=MY_API_KEY";

    //fetch json response from googleapis.com:
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $shippingurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    //If google responds with a status of OK
    //Extract the distance text:
    if($response['status'] == "OK"){
        $dist = $response['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    }

    // Get only number from string
    $distance= filter_var ( $dist, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    // Distance example
    //$distance = 3.5; //(in KM)

    if( $distance > 5 )
        $cost_operator = 3; // (3 * 50 = 150)
    elseif( $distance > 3 && $distance <= 5 )
        $cost_operator = 2; // (2 * 50 = 100)
    else
        $cost_operator = 1; // (1 * 50 = 50)

    // Iterating through each shipping rate
    foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate_values){
        $method_id = $rate_values->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate_values->id;

        // Targeting "Flat Rate" shipping method
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $rate_values->method_id ) {
            // Set the new calculated rate cost
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost = number_format($rates[$rate_id]->cost * $cost_operator, 2);
            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_id]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){ // set the new tax cost
                    $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] = number_format( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] * $cost_operator, 2 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First you will set a **"Flat rate"** Shipping method for each Shipping zone **with a cost of 50** (you can enable tax or not).
2. You should add a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_package_rates`** filter hook.
3. In this custom function you will have to set your API code to get the distance between customer and vendor.

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'distance_shipping_calculated_surcharge', 100, 2 );
function distance_shipping_calculated_surcharge( $rates, $package ) {

    ## HERE set your API code to get the distance ##

    // Distance example
    $distance = 3.5; //(in KM)

    if( $distance > 5 )
        $cost_operator = 3; // (3 * 50 = 150)
    elseif( $distance > 3 && $distance <= 5 )
        $cost_operator = 2; // (2 * 50 = 100)
    else
        $cost_operator = 1; // (1 * 50 = 50)

    // Iterating through each shipping rate
    foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate_values){
        $method_id = $rate_values->method_id;
        $rate_id = $rate_values->id;

        // Targeting "Flat Rate" shipping method
        if ( 'flat_rate' === $rate_values->method_id ) {
            // Set the new calculated rate cost
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost = number_format($rates[$rate_id]->cost * $cost_operator, 2);
            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_id]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){ // set the new tax cost
                    $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] = number_format( $rates[$rate_id]->taxes[$key] * $cost_operator, 2 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works.

> **Sometimes is necessary to refresh the shipping caches:** 
>   1) First your cart is empty. 
>   2) The code is already saved on your function.php file. 
>   3) Go in a shipping zone and disable one "flat rate" *(for example)* and "save". Then re-enable that "flat rate" and "save". **You are done.**

Comment: Hi @loictheaztec, Thank you for your cooperation. Unfortunately, it's not working for me. Please see the answer below as it's too long to write here.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the question again? I have added few lines at the bottom of the question.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the distance in Km between the vendor and customer.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_shipping_add_rate','add_another_custom_flat_rate', 10, 2 );

function add_another_custom_flat_rate( $method, $rate ) {
$new_rate          = $rate;

/*let the distance is = $dis; */
if($dis==3){
$new_rate['cost']  = 50; // Update the cost to 50
} else if($dis<=5){
$new_rate['cost']  = 100; // Update the cost to 100
} else {
$new_rate['cost']  = 150; // Update the cost to 150
}


$method->add_rate( $new_rate );
}
```